# insufficient_scope error with docker registry v2 and curl

Tags: bash, curl, docker

I'n attempting to access the docker hub via the v2 registry and cannot understand why I'm getting an `insufficient_scope` error returned in the headers.

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO=ubuntu
TAG=latest
REGISTRY=https://registry-1.docker.io/v2

URI="$REGISTRY/$REPO/manifests/$TAG"
echo URI=$URI
MANIFEST="`curl -skL -o /dev/null -D- $URI`"
CHALLENGE="`grep "Www-Authenticate" <<<"$MANIFEST"`"
if [[ CHALLENGE ]]; then
    IFS=\" read _ REALM _ SERVICE _ SCOPE _ <<<"$CHALLENGE"
    echo REALM is $REALM
    echo SERVICE is $SERVICE
    echo SCOPE is $SCOPE
    TOKEN="`curl -skL "$REALM?service=$SERVICE&scope=$SCOPE"`"
    IFS=\" read _ _ _ TOKEN _ <<<"$TOKEN"
    echo TOKEN is $TOKEN
    MANIFEST="`curl -isk -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $URI`"
    echo "RESPONSE is $MANIFEST"
fi
```

console output is:

```
URI=https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ubuntu/manifests/latest
REALM is https://auth.docker.io/token
SERVICE is registry.docker.io
SCOPE is repository:ubuntu:pull
TOKEN is 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.eyJhY2Nlc3MiOltdLCJhdWQiOiJyZWdpc3RyeS5kb2NrZXIuaW8iLCJleHAiOjE0NjgyNTU4ODgsImlhdCI6MTQ2ODI1NTU4OCwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aC5kb2NrZXIuaW8iLCJqdGkiOiJBc2R5ZzBiX0hnNlNDS2Z0MEgtMiIsIm5iZiI6MTQ2ODI1NTU4OCwic3ViIjoiIn0.6pCh0OIabGGbBd8mubOpwlighlX69P7tMFqGk5P-knsJqxw7-G9YzaY-5_gUKRb44NvaJAeib84EYa0AejbUSw
RESPONSE is HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="repository:ubuntu:pull",error="insufficient_scope"
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 16:46:31 GMT
Content-Length: 138
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Name":"ubuntu","Action":"pull"}]}]
```

The echoes are all what I'm expecting, so I'm currently stumped.

I've only been able to uncover [this](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1589) ticket on google but it doesn't shed any light on my situation.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across this article, the issue seems to be that there is no `ubuntu` repository (not public at least).  Substituting `REPO=library/ubuntu` seems to have resolved it.